# Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=null, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)

Tags: react, console, state-variable, wagmi, nextjs

Within my front end part, I am using **Wagmi's** `usePrepareContractWrite` and `useContractWrite` hooks to execute a function of my smart contract.

The function demands a `uint` argument. Therefore my 'usePrepareContractWrite' hook looks like this:

```
const { config } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    address,
    abi,
    functionName: 'createItem',
    args: [price],
})
```

The **price** is a state variable that gets updated once the user updates the form within the front-end. So when a user enters a `uint` at the input, that will feed this hook and prepare it for further steps.

However, when I start my project and head over to this page comprised of inputs and wagmi's hooks, I encounter the error below on my console. It probably is related to the relation between input and hook.

```
Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=null, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (index.js?dd68:224:1)
    at Logger.throwError (index.js?dd68:233:1)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (index.js?dd68:236:1)
    at BigNumber.from (bignumber.js?248a:233:1)
    at NumberCoder.encode (number.js?ee34:16:17)
    at eval (array.js?4375:57:1)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at pack (array.js?4375:43:1)
    at TupleCoder.encode (tuple.js?1c6b:51:20)
    at AbiCoder.encode (abi-coder.js?2acc:86:1)
    at Interface._encodeParams (interface.js?1df7:253:1)
    at Interface.encodeFunctionData (interface.js?1df7:295:1)
    at eval (index.js?b70c:125:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (index.js?b70c:5:43)
```

Basically, when the user has not specified any number yet for the input ( Like when the page renders for the first time ), this error shows up. It might be trying to feed the hook but is unsuccessful since the price state variable is null yet.

Does anyone know how I can stop this error from being thrown every time the page renders?

Comment: I met the same issue, any update how to resolve it?

Comment: I initialized all of my numeral state variables with a zero value like `const [ number, setNumber ] = useState(0)` and the error disappeared, but I'm not sure that's the best solution

Answer (score 0):

From the given info my conclusion is that when you call the function, the value of the price is still null. Try `console.log(typeOf(price))` to check if the value of the price is updated when you call the function.

If it's not, maybe try `price && functionName(args)` . The price here basically means execute the function only when the price has value set.